# How do i add the `pip install --user` bin to my PATH?

Tags: python, pip

When I install a binary by using `pip install --user <package>`, it gets installed to `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin`, but this path isn't on my PATH.  Obviously I could add `PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Python/3.6/bin` to my bashrc/zshrc, but when I upgrade to python 3.7 I'd have to modify this.

It seems like when I installed pip, it should have done something to add that directory to my PATH.  Is there a recommended way to install pip so that it automatically manages adding the appropriate bin to my path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands no, I do mean PATH.  For example, I would install ipython by doing `pip install --user ipython`, and it will get installed to `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin/ipython`.  Now I'd like to be able to run `ipython` from my zsh shell, but since `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin` isn't on my path, I'm unable to without specifying the full path.  Other examples would be commands like fab (Fabric) or virtualenv, which I want always available.  These work if I use `sudo pip install`, but I'm trying to avoid installing as root.

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend a symlink?

```
ln -s ~/Library/Python/3.6/bin ~/bin
```

Then add `~/bin` to `PATH` in your `.bashrc`.

Before installing Python 3.7 you save the list of installed packages:

```
pip freeze > packages.list
```

install Python 3.7, change the link:

```
ln -fs ~/Library/Python/3.7/bin ~/bin
```

and reinstall saved list of packages:

```
pip install -r packages.list
```

Comment: Is this necessary in pip 19.1.1 ? Or does the pip doc say how it finds a `.../bin` directory ? (I find symlinks errorprone, long cuts.) Thanks

Comment: The question was how to switch from Python 3.6 to 3.7 without modifying `~/.bash_profile`. Switching symlinks is the answer.

Answer (score -2):

If running python is fine then something like this:

```
PYVER=`python3 -c "import platform;(a,b,_)=platform.python_version_tuple();print(f'{a}.{b}')"`
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/$PYVER/bin:$PATH"
```